# First h:form of an a4j:repeat is not rendering correctly

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Let's say that I have a list of objects in my bean and I want to paint them in my page, for that I'm using an `<a4j:repeat>`, this objects need to be wrapped inside a `<h:form>` because each one of this objects needs to run a poll to execute some Futures Java objects in the bean to perform some heavy tasks and update them later on.

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{bean.objectsList}" var="obj">

  <h:form id="pollForm">
   
    <a4j:poll id="myPoll" interval="2000"
              action="#{myBean.foo1}"                       
              enabled="#{myBean.foo2}"                      
              render="pollForm,myPoll" />

    <p>#{obj}</p>

  </h:form>

</a4j:repeat>
```

The code isn't really relevant I think. My code works as excepted in all elements except the first one. All the elements inside the loop render as an html form element except the first one, and for that reason the first one can't never be reRendered by the poll.

I have read in other posts that it seems to be a bug, but I'm also new to JSF 2.2 and RichFaces and maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: It is bad idea to have multiple forms with the same id "pollForm" on the same page. Change form id to be different per each element inside a4j:repeat or change design to use 1 form per proposed fragment (to be outside of a4j:repeat) and use h:panelGroup as wrapper for re-rendering part inside a4j:repeat (replace h:form with h:panelGroup inside a4j:repeat). Note: you can use keywords "@this", "@form", ... in a4j instead of specific ids.

Comment: I ended up doing this with the help of another partner, but the problem with the ids is still in the air, I wanted to build ids like "pollForm-#{obj.id}", but the EL doesn't display his value, form example I expect something like "pollForm-12", but instead I get "pollForm-", the attribute obj.id is obviusly not empty, basically because I'm using it later on other elements. Any idea why this happens? And another question, If I don't use Ids, can I put in the render @form if it's a h:panelGroup?

Comment: @form can be used for re-rendering parent form, but not h:panelGroup